# C# Entity Framework Create two DbContext´s in the same database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I´ve got an generic DbContext which holds a context, when ever I want to save a Model in DB I want to create an Instance of this class an just save the Object. In a test I assert that, the first Object is saved properly but the second does throw an exception `"No such Table"`. To clear that, it does throw this exception if I call my Controller with an other Model which was not created before. The test below shows it. When I look at the actual created Database, there is only one Table in it.

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Here my DbContext:

```
    public class DbEntryController<TEntity> : DbContext
    where TEntity : class
{
    protected static NLog.Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static object _locker = new();

    public DbSet<TEntity> Context { get; set; }

    private string _tableName;

    public DbEntryController(string tableName, DbContextOptions<DbEntryController<TEntity>> options) 
        : base(options)
    {
        _tableName = tableName;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>().ToTable(_tableName, schema: typeof(TEntity).Name);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var entries = ChangeTracker
         .Entries()
         .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseEntry 
         && (e.State == EntityState.Added
         || e.State == EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
        {
            ((BaseEntry)entityEntry.Entity).LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

            if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((BaseEntry)entityEntry.Entity).CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        Database.EnsureCreated();
        Database.Migrate();

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public bool TryAddReceived<T>(string content, T context)
        where T : TEntity, IReceiveDbEntry
    {
        return this.Save(Direction.Received, content, context);
    }

    public bool TryAddSent<T>(string content, T context)
        where T : TEntity, ISendDbEntry
    {
        return this.Save(Direction.Sent, content, context);
    }
}
```

Here is how I create an instance of it:

```
using var db = DbController.FromDBPath<DbEntryController<MyModel>>((options) => new DbEntryController<MyModel>(nameof(MyModel), options));
```

And here the FromDBPath method:

```
        public static TContext FromDBPath<TContext>(Func<DbContextOptions<TContext>, TContext> creator, string dbPath = null)
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        if (dbPath == null)
            Log.Trace($"No DB Path given. Use: {dbPath = Configuration.Instance.SQLiteDbPath}");

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>();

        try
        {
            Log.Trace("Try use sqlite");
            builder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={Path.GetFullPath(dbPath)}");

            Log.Trace("Try create EventLoggingContext");
            var e = creator(builder.Options);
            e.Database.EnsureCreated();

            Log.Trace("DB Create success");

            return e;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Could not create DB");
            Log.Error(ex);

            return creator(builder.Options);
        }
    }
```

The test I´ve written in nunit framework:

```
        [Test]
    public void InsertSoapRequest()
    {

        var sequence = new SequenceNumberDbEntry { Next = 2000000000 };

        Assert.True(sequence.SuperFancyCreateXmlMethod(out var xml));

        using (var db = (EventLoggingContext)DbController.FromDBPath<DbEntryController<Event>>((options) => new EventLoggingContext("InOut", options), dbPath))
        {
            Assert.True(db.TryAddEvent(xml, Direction.Received));
            Assert.True(db.TryAddEvent(xml, Direction.Sent));
            
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var db = DbController.FromDBPath<DbEntryController<MyModel>>((options) => new DbEntryController<MyModel>("SequenceNumbers", options), dbPath))
        {

            db.TryAddReceived(xml, sequence);
            var max = db.SelectMaxTransaktionId();

            Assert.AreEqual(2000000000, max);
        }
    }
```

The Exception:

[image]

And last but not least my Model:

```
    [Table("SequenceNumbers", Schema = nameof(MyModel))]
public class MyModel : BaseEntry, ISendDbEntry, IReceiveDbEntry
{
    public uint Next { get; set; }
    public uint Previos { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceiveTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime SendTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `I´ve got an generic DbContext which holds a context` why??? DbContext is already generic Unit-of-Work and can have an arbitrary number of **entities**. What does the `Save` method do and what is the actual, full exception? `SaveChanges` is definitely buggy - do you really need to create a new database on every save?

Comment: It looks like the only thing that's actually needed in the derived class is setting the `CreationTime` and `LastUpdate` audit columns. In EF Core 5 there's no need to derive from DbContext to do this. You can use [SaveChanges interception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#savechanges-interception) to add auditing to any DbContext-derived class instead of having to derive from it. The doc sample goes farther than just setting a couple of columns and stores changes in a separate audit table.

Comment: `.EnsureCreated()` only checks that a database exists. It doesn't check that it is up-to-date or that the model for this context has been created. Though it does return a boolean, so you might be able to test one context then force the second to be created via `IRelationalDatabaseCreator.CreateTables()` (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/eb0e6d856b02c6e8a88bd1a5cc9c9eb5b0d50e40/src/EFCore.Relational/Storage/RelationalDatabaseCreator.cs#L129).